# aspnet core: need id in all routes after after login into application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am new to aspnet core. I am developing an application. I have a requirement. I need to pass a userId in all routes after login. let me clarify my requirement more. When user log-in to the system then system will redirect user to dashboard page (containing the userId in route). And in all actions (performed from dashboard) get and post I need that userId to be passed on recursively.

How can I do this in ASP.CORE MVC routing?

Comment: are you sure you want to pass around a user id? that does not seem very secure. the user id should be available in the httpcontext of your controllers anyway.

Comment: I dont exactly want to pass arround a user id. Someother ID I want to pass on. For the sake of simplicity, I used the word userId. @Markus Dresch

Comment: I think @MarkusDresch 's option of the User already available in the HttpContext is cleaner option than in the router. In the [ClaimsPrimcipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=netcore-2.1) you can add Claims, one of those can be the id you want to keep track of.

Comment: First of all what authentication system are you using? the build in identity?

Comment: You should be getting userid from claim not from routes.

Answer (score 0):

UserId in url is not a good idea. You can use Asp.net Identity to achieve this, and then you just need to add UserId into claim. and then you can retrieve it wherever you want.